# If i have two Xms values in set in VM options which one is picked?

Tags: memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory

I am setting below two in Vm options

-Xmx1g -Xmx32g

Which one will be used ?

Comment: Why not try and see?

Comment: You should edit your question. The title talks about `-Xms` and the description about `-Xmx`.

Answer (score 1):

The later will be used. You can try this to check it:

```
java -Xms4g -Xms2g -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal 2> /dev/null | grep MinHeapSi
   size_t MinHeapSize                              = 2147483648                                {product} {command line}
```